# How to get included views with Android Databinding?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding

I'm playing with [Android databinding library](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) and I'm trying to use it with included layouts.

The code I have is like this:

activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id = "@+id/linearLayout">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view" />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

view.xml

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id = "@+id/myView">
 </View>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = mBinding.linearLayout; // this field is visible
    View myView  = mBinding.myView // THIS FIELD IS NOT VISIBLE
  }


}
```

As I have written in comments the view myView which is declared in an "included" layout is not visible. If I replace the  with the actual code in the view.xml then mBinding.myView becomes visible, the cause seems to be the include then.

The official documentation states only that

> "Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element."
>   but in my case View is a child of LinearLayout, it's not a direct child..

Any hints?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to provide an ID to the include statement:

```
<include android:id="@+id/included"
    layout="@layout/view" />
```

Now you can access the include view:

```
View myView = mBinding.included;
```

If your included layout is a binding layout, the include will be a generated Binding. For example, if view.xml is:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@{@android:color/black}"
        android:id="@+id/myView"/>
</layout>
```

then the layout field will be a ViewBinding class:

```
View myView = mBinding.included.myView;
```

Comment: How can I do the same but for two layouts with same name, this for layout for tablet case. I mean, when I have two layout named `layout/layout.xml` and `layout-sw600dp/layout.xml` but the second one has a container `FrameLayout` for fragments, this last does not appears in the binding generated class. In advance thanks.

Comment: If you have a view in one layout, but not both, you should see the view in the class, but it will be null when one layout is bound. Make sure to give IDs to views that you want to have as properties.

Comment: @GeorgeMount this is just not working for. I have follows the advice of this answer, the medium blog post you wrote and read many stackoverflow answers where people claim to have done nothing it just magically started working again but for me its been two hours and its not working. Is there anything happening 7 years later that has changed and that I might have overlooked?